# How to handle messages in a Telegram Bot?

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

My goal is to make a Telegram Bot using Python that does the following:

1. The user types a command
2. The bot explains what the user should type next.
3. The user types certain information
4. I use that info to fetch a value in a python dictionary.
5. The bot replies with that info

I have already created the bot and set the command. The problem is that I don't know how to keep the bot "listening" . I have looked up in the docs but I have only found getUpdates, which gets the user's responses but only when you hit run.

```
res=requests.get(url=f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/getUpdates")
```

I would like to set a webhook, and I know there is a method for this but I'm not shure about how this works.

Answer (score 1):

When you are a PHP programmer, setting the webhook through a URL and using `setWebhook` would do the trick and telegram will send the result to this link whenever a user sends an update to the bot.  But, Python programmers have to use a different approach, I think. The main, and while, the easiest approach to make the bot listen permanently to the request is to `python-telegram-bot` module.

There are a few links that can help to build your first pythonic bot that can respond to users' updates.:

- [Python-Telegram-Bot Repository](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot), which is the repository of the module.
- [A few examples of bots](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples) created using this module, can give you insight into the process of creating your first bot.
- [A conversation bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py)

Comment: There's no language bias with setWebhook. It's just HTTP. A typical setup for Python is import a WSGI capable module like gevent or gunicorn, and have it listen for web requests, then use nginx proxy_pass directive to forward requests from your web server to the Python service.